# Filter an array and map in then in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary, filter

I am working on a filter / map function which is the following :

```js
  <div className ="filteredSitter" >
          <h4> Available sitters </h4>
          <h5> Click on their name to get in touch with them</h5>
           {sitters.filter(InitialSitter => InitialSitter.locationSitter === "London").map(filteredSitter => (
        <li onClick = {function (){alert(`${filteredSitter.nameSitter} is located in ${filteredSitter.locationSitter} and his phone number is ${filteredSitter.phoneSitter}`);}}>
          {filteredSitter.nameSitter}
        </li>
      ))}
            
        </div>
```

My question is - instead of using "London" as a forced comparison, I would like to use the latest person who inserted her data in owners form (I tried using
`props.owners.locationOwner`but it did not work.)
Any idea how to compare with the location of the person being part of a state ?

Here is the state and the initial owners I have ( so I want to comopare with the location of the additional user coming in this array).

```js
let InitialOwners = [
  { nameOwner: 'Jim', locationOwner: "Barcelona", phoneOwner: "+34 671 872 000" , startDateOwner: "01/03/2021" , endDateOwner : "08/03/2021" },
  { nameOwner: 'Jessica', locationOwner: "Paris", phoneOwner: "+34 651 871 000" , startDateOwner: "20/03/2021" , endDateOwner : "28/03/2021" }
];

function App() {

 
  const [owners, setOwners] = useState(InitialOwners);
  
  .....
```

THANK YOU !!

Comment: hey, can you share the full component?

Comment: Sure ! here you go !! 

import React  from "react";

function PlantSittingOffers({sitters}){


    return ( 

      
        <div className ="filteredSitter" >
           {sitters.filter(InitialSitter => InitialSitter.locationSitter === "London").map(filteredSitter => (
        <li onClick = {function (){alert(`${filteredSitter.nameSitter} is located in ${filteredSitter.locationSitter} and his phone number is ${filteredSitter.phoneSitter}`);}}>
          {filteredSitter.nameSitter}
        </li>
      ))}
            
        </div> 
)
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
owners[owners.length - 1].locationOwner
```

Comment: Thank you for the help unfortunately does not seem to work :( 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined